# GNU make: Non-optimal execution time if long task present

Tags: performance, gnu-make

My makefile contains single long task with short requirements and many other short tasks. Make starts the long task too late. So total execution time is not optimal. Reduced example:

```
sleep = ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w $(1)000 > nul || exit 0


all : m6 m5 m4 m3 m2 m1

m1 :
    $(call sleep, 6)

m2 :
    $(call sleep, 6)

m3 :
    $(call sleep, 6)

m4 :
    $(call sleep, 6)

m5 : m6
    $(call sleep, 20)

m6 :
    $(call sleep, 4)
```

It is executed using 'make -j 2'. Current execution plan is:

```
[m6][-m3-][-m1-]
[-m4-][-m2-][--------m5--------]
```

e. g. 32 seconds. Optimal execution plan is:

```
[-m1-][-m2-][-m3-][-m4-]
[m6][--------m5--------]
```

e. g. 24 seconds. How to rich the optimal execution time?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how you can possibly expect make to do this for you. It can't possibly know which of your jobs are going to take a long time and which are not.

make would need to support length estimate annotations or something like that for this to even begin to be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Make always starts jobs in the same order, starting from the first prerequisite to the last.  So if you put all your long-running prerequisite first in the list of prerequisites then your build will be "more optimal".  In theory you could get close to optimal by ordering things as:

```
all : m5 m4 m3 m2 m1 m6
```

The short answer is, make has no way to know how long things will take, nor is there any way for you to tell make that some commands will be slow or estimate how long they will take, nor is there any infrastructure internal to make that could take advantage of that information to produce a "best order" even if it was available.

And finally, since the jobserver spans multiple make instances all sharing the same pool of jobs if you have recursive make invocations, and there's no way for those make instances to communicate estimated job times to each other, the whole thing is just not workable in general.

The best you can do is arrange the order of your prerequisites to be as efficient as possible given what you know about the build times.

Comment: Suggested order "all : m5 m4 m3 m2 m1 m6" has same execution plan as original because "m5 : m6".

Comment: Oh right.  Well, `all: m6 m5 m1 m2 m3 m4` then.  Either way, my main point stands: the only way to exercise any control over the order of invocation is by perturbing the order of the prerequisite list.